# Я пытаюсь отобразить названия новостей с сайта http://hkotso.ru/novosti, но в коде отображается ошибка

Tags: python, парсер

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs 

r = requests.get('http://hkotso.ru/novosti') 
html = bs(r.content,'html.parser')

for el in html.select('.views-row-odd'):
    title = el.select('.media-heading > a')
    print(title.text) 

for el in html.select('.views-row-even'):
    title = el.select('.media-heading > a')
    print(title.text)
```

Этот код выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "par.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(title.string)
  File "C:\Users\max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 2080, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'string'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

Я пытаюсь отобразить названия новостей с сайта http://hkotso.ru/novosti, но в коде отображается ошибка

Comment: на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Comment: Специально для вас перевел.

Comment: Максим, специально для меня не надо.  А вот соблюдать правила сервиса - дело полезное.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
import requests


def page_proc(page: Soup) -> list:
    news_headers = []
    for header in page.find_all('h4', {'class': 'media-heading'}):
        news_headers.append(header.text.strip())
    return news_headers


def sandbox(base_url: str) -> list:
    headers = []
    with requests.Session() as session:
        first_page = Soup(session.get(base_url).content, 'html.parser')
        pages_qty = int(first_page.find('li', {'class': 'pager-last'}).a['href'].rpartition('=')[-1])

        headers.extend(page_proc(first_page))

        for p in range(2, pages_qty + 1):
            pg = Soup(session.get(base_url + f'?page={p}').content, 'html.parser')
            headers.extend(page_proc(pg))

        return headers


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(sandbox('http://hkotso.ru/novosti'))
```